# nginx - 502 Bad Gateway for some ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, nginx

I get 502 Bad Gateway for some requests on my server. I get it for some particular AJAX requests but if I replay the failed request in the console, it works (wtf). In `nginx/error.log` it says

> [error] 13867#0: *74180 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream

My website is in PHP. Thanx

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: what part of code? There's a lot of it...

Answer (score 8):

I had similar problem on wordpress site. add these lines inside `http` block of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.

```
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 10m;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 512k;
fastcgi_buffers 16 512k;
```

If it still not working also add this line

```
 client_max_body_size 50M;
```

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem with my gitlab setup on nginx. What helped solve my problem was to higher max client's body size by `client_max_body_size 50m` directive inside `http` block of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.

Comment: Having the same problem for certain pages where I do AJAX requests with credentials. It fails when I have a huge session cookie. Thanks for this answer which should fix it. Though we shouldn't save session data in a cookie to begin with...