# SilverStripe - Bad gateway error on admin/pages

Tags: silverstripe

In SilverStripe 3.1 when accessing pages in the admin section I get an error message saying *Bad Gateway*, as can be seen in the following screen shot.

[image: Admin bad gateway screenshot]

None of the pages or site tree will load in the admin section.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you turned the site to dev mode to see if it gives a more detailed error message? To turn the site to dev mode add `Director::set_environment_type('dev');` to your config file. Is your web server `nginx` or `apache`? Have you checked if there is an error log on your server with details of this issue? There are a few posts on the [SilverStripe forum describing similar issues](https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/24143) as well as [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/chtombleson/8703899).

Comment: Sounds like a php error somewhere in your code causing a 500 error. As 3dgoo said: switch to dev mode and try to get the error somehow (webserver error log, silverstripe error log, checking the response in firebug...). Hitting "reload" or F5 can also show you the error in your browser, as the whole page gets reloaded and hits the bad code.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I flushed /dev/build and /pages and after a few moments it started to working.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SilverStripe 4 with nginx. Using the settings mentioned in this answer did the trick: [nginx - 502 Bad Gateway for some ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637160/nginx-502-bad-gateway-for-some-ajax-requests#55095572)